# How do I access this hashed/compressed/encrypted backup data when I'm the owner?

Tags: backup, encryption, data-recovery, compression

I recently did a backup of my xperia phone onto my computer using the Xperia Companion Application.

I *checked* to backup **apps** and **media** in the procedure.

After everything finished, I looked at the backup contents (specifically the media folder that got created) and I noticed that it's all **compressed or hashed or encrypted files**. 
(not really sure what I'm looking at here)

They have no file extension and look like this:
[image: file-preview]

I assume that every file in that folder is an actual media file because there's approximately the same number of files on my phone gallery.

The backup also contains a **manifest.xml** file.

I assume the program uses the information from the manifest to recover the data on the new phone as it contains backup-version information, hashed data info (specifically 'passwordHash', 'passwordIterations', 'passwordSalt') and some personal information as well.

Before the backup I gave the application access to my google drive account to store some key, so I assume that manifest also contains info for that.

I was very curious if it's possible to recover those files on my computer instead of a new phone, because the companion software only allows recoveries to a new phone and even then there are certain limitations, as suggested by this hint in the program:

[image: important-notice]

I'm really interested in how I would go about to analyze those files / data and to figure out a way to recover the actual files from this backup.

It's more of a curiousity adventure as currently my phone hasn't died yet (thankfully), but I figured, if my phone ever died and this was the only backup I had, I would have no way of getting my data without buying a new phone from the same brand or at least type. 
So it made me curious if there's another way.

But when it comes to forensics like this I'm a complete noob, **so I'd like to ask where I should start with this or what I could possibly do?**

*(Aside from contacting sony support)*

Comment: Those are most likely encrypted files.  Hashes dont contain information, they are used for comparison.  As for how you would decrypt them, that is way to broad to cover.

Comment: Why would it be too broad?